# GoogleMap disable 3d buildings in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to display only 2D buildings. But by default, Google maps will display all the buildings in 3D.
How can you display buildings only in 2D?

In this case, all buildings are turned off.

```
mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = false
```

In this case, all buildings are turned off.

```
mapView.mapType = .terrain
```

Didnt work. Still see 3d buildings

```
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
```

This is simple task, but i dont understand how display buildings in 2D instead of 3D

Comment: chcek this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views